# iphone - How to implement the effect of "float" for image, just like in CSS style

Tags: iphone, css-float

In HTML, with CSS, one can do "float" for images, just like this

[image: Float effect for image and text]

the image is surrounded by text.

How can I do it **WITHOUT UIWebView**?

I can't use UIWebview, because

1. UIWebView has a slight lag after you loadHTML. Its content doesn't show immediately, not like UILabel or UIImage
2. The image is async loaded, so I need a white space holder there with UIActivityView spinning

Is that possible I just use a UIImageView & UILabel to do **float**?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "easy" way is probably to use *two* labels and an image. If your text/images are static, then you can split the text at the right place beforehand. If not, you'll have to do some text size measurements; see [UIStringDrawing.h](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html). Figuring out where all the line breaks should be is non-trivial.

The "hard" way is to create your own subclass of UIView with `text` and `image` properties and have it do all the string/image layout and drawing. It's not actually that much harder than figuring out where the line breaks should be dynamically.

The "harder" way is to use Core Text (iOS 3.2+); the [Columnar Layout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Operations/Operations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH4-SW19) example in the Core Text Programming Guide should work, but also note that `CTFramesetterCreateFrame()` can take an arbitrary CGPath, so you can just pass it a path of the available area. This might actually be slightly easier than using UIKit string-sizing and trying to find out where all the line breaks are (you just need to write a lot of Core Text boilerplate instead).

Comment: Thanks!!! Obviously I will try easy way first. but from UIStringDrawing.h I only know the size for a NSString, but how do I know where the line breaks? or How many words for one fixed size?