# How to float text around image in react native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to achieve a very common effect in react native of having text wrap around an image. On the web you would assign a `float` property to the image and follow it with a `p` tag.  [image: Here is how I want my elements to flow].

Here is a [RNPlay example](https://rnplay.org/apps/_s6X_Q) I've been working on. I think the method I currently have is a bit hackish, and doesn't properly work since the text does not align with the top of the image and flow down. Is there a proper and clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: there is a closed issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4563 , you can try to contact its author may be

Comment: @Cherniv Unfortunately I am not able to comment on that issue. That question was asked close to a year ago, so I have hope that perhaps there is a solution now.

Comment: Hahaha awesome drawing!

Comment: Still no solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `Text` as container instead of the typical `View`.

```
<Text style={{flex: 1}}>
  <Image source={Images.IconExplore} style={{ width: 16, height: 16 }} />
  <Text> Your past has been in control for far too long. It's time to shift to a higher expression of what you are capable of so you can create the life you want to live.</Text>
</Text>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, however on ios i cant get the text to line up to the top of the image. Here is screenshot - https://i.imgur.com/CTsf4Sw.png and another - https://i.imgur.com/rPQt1vS.png - i didnt try in android but i think the `verticalTextAlign` property would fix it in android.

Comment: This is cool but it only works if image is same height as line-height. Any ideas on multiple lines? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216957/wrapping-multiple-lines-of-text-around-inline-image

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is still no easy way to do it, even after the introduction of nested `View`s inside `Text`. Surprisingly in the iOS community this seems to be non-trivial.

[iphone - How to implement the effect of "float" for image, just like in CSS style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402857/iphone-how-to-implement-the-effect-of-float-for-image-just-like-in-css-styl)
https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/issues/438

One idea that comes to mind that would be worth tinkering around with is measuring the text, dimensions and/or character count, and depending on the size of the image, divide the text into two `Text` components, one that goes to the right/left and the other that goes below the image.

There is this under-promoted React Native library that might help, which allows you to measure the width and height of a `Text` component based on its content:

https://github.com/alinz/react-native-swiss-knife/blob/master/lib/text/index.ios.js