# How to make " text wrap around image " by using React Native

Tags: react-native

How to make the text wrap around Image by using react native?
This is the example image.

[image]

Comment: Checkout my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514335/how-to-float-text-around-image-in-react-native/58171021#58171021) about this

Comment: @J.C.Gras that answer has issue of vertical text alignment on ios.