# row direction fill remaining space react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want second view fill to bottom remaining space like the below image, is there any possible solution

[image]

Comment: check this might help 
https://css-tricks.com/working-with-shapes-in-web-design/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to float text around image in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514335/how-to-float-text-around-image-in-react-native)