# How can I get Text Around Image in react native?

Tags: react-native

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Text style={{textAlign: 'justify'}}>
        Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in
        laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to
        an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have
        scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a
        type specimen book.
    </Text>
    <Image
        source={{
            uri: item.url,
        }}
        style={{
            height: 180,
            width: 180,
        }}
    />
</View>
```

Comment: Duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514335/how-to-float-text-around-image-in-react-native#58171021

Answer (score 0):

```html
<Text style={{flex: 1}}>
  <Image source={Images.IconExplore} style={{ width: 16, height: 16 }} />
  <Text> Check in this type.</Text>
</Text>
```

Comment: did you just copy paste code from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514335/how-to-float-text-around-image-in-react-native#58171021 and given as answer instead commenting that this question is duplicate